# Unable to generate the Access Token and a Refresh Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive

I'm trying to perform a file transfer automation to OneDrive. For that, I need to generate an access token and refresh token from the Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps. However, I completed all the previous steps successfully.

Below is my POST REQUEST

````
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 119

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```. 
client_id -> Client ID generated from the APP
code -> Code generated by the below url
````

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=your_app_client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient&response_mode=query&scope=User.Read%20offline_access%20Files.ReadWrite

```
Unfortunately I'm getting 404  always as response. May I know what is missing my code or I miss any certification or license. Anyway please help me to find out the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems missing some parameters such as `scope`, `redirect_uri` and `client_secret`, but I didn't reproduce your problem. So I provide the details of my request for your reference, in my test the request is successful.

[image]

For further information about authorization code flow, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token).

By the way, it seems there are some minor problems in your request. I noticed another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465379/unable-to-access-the-access-code-and-refresh-token-of-aad-microsoft-app) you raised. According to the information from that post, I think you may need to check if the `Content-Type` is right and it seems you put the parameters in the query url follow the request url even if you used `post` method. You may need to put the parameters in the request body but not in the query url. If you put them in the query url follow the request url, they will not be retrieved in the backend code. The backend code will retrieve the parameter `grant_type` first, so it will always show `must contain grant_type` error.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Is redirect Uri necessary

Comment: Change to formurlencoded and got "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://garph.microsoft.com was not found in the tenant named 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 14e14b3f-19a2-48e1-9c52-b83eebaf9d00\r\nCorrelation ID: 958773fc-1ee2-4e62-8cce-d01c30ffd4e2\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-28 04:47:01Z

Comment: Hi @EdwardArrow May I know if this issue and the issue in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465379/unable-to-access-the-access-code-and-refresh-token-of-aad-microsoft-app#61465379) is the same issue ? In that post, you can have a try to put the parameters from the query url to the body form in your postman.

Comment: I resolved the issue. it was related to scope parameter

Comment: @EdwardArrow That's great~

Comment: Do you know how can we get the client ID of azure active directory if we give username and password using python