# Unable to access the access code and refresh token of AAD Microsoft App

Tags: azure-active-directory

[image]I'm trying to automate the file transfer between one drive and Linux. Hence I need to generate the access token and refresh token.

My POST URL is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?grant_type='authorization_code'&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

getting below error as below

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9001442323: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 55c2b449-381b-41844ads5a2f-b2b7-451d65188500\r\nCorrelation ID: bf082e8f-99be-41e0-87dd-756894601365\r\nTimestamp: 2020-04-27 17:54:21Z",
    "error_codes": [
        90043234144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-04-27 17:54:21Z",
    "trace_id": "55cadsasdad2b449-381b-412f-b2b7-451d65188500",
    "correlation_id": "bf0asdadada82e8f-99be-41e0-87dd-75688dasda94601365",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=90014486"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the value of the header `Content-Type`. Then this error will not exist.

But based on your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461135/unable-to-generate-the-access-token-and-a-refresh-token), you have set the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So if it's not the reason for this issue, please provide more details: **Where are you generating the access token? In Postman? Could you provide a screenshot?**

But there is another error. You should use `grant_type=authorization_code` instead of `grant_type='authorization_code'`.

And you should provide some other parameters. See this sample: [Request an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token).

Comment: Screenshot is added

Comment: I need to perform a file transfer between Linux and one drive using python script. So I need access token and refresh token to make this automate

Comment: @EdwardArrow Put the parameters into Body. Don't use them in the Params. See this https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXFYP.png.

Comment: I got its  Thanks for your contribution